# How can I fetch all SiteRelated objects for all sites in Mezzanine?

Tags: django, mezzanine

I don't know if this is by design of Mezzanine or Django. I can't find any information about it though. Here's the object: https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/models.py#L15

**What I want:**

Get ALL entries of an object. In this case the `BlogPost` object in Mezzanine. At the moment I can only retrieve the entries of the current site.

How could I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Mezzanine thing.

`BlogPost`, and indeed most other Mezzanine models, subclass [`SiteRelated`](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/packages.html#mezzanine.core.models.SiteRelated) which sets the manager of the object to filter results for the current site. So `BlogPost.objects.all()` will filter results for the current site.

There is a sneaky hack you can use to bypass this manager:

```
BlogPost._base_manager.all()
```

This will fetch all objects for all sites.